# Magento 2 - passing variable output to another variable in email template

Tags: magento2, orders, magento2.2.2, order-items, order-confirmation-email

I'm working on **order confirmation email** and I want to pass variable output:

```
{{var order.getMyCustomItem().getSomething('key')}}
```

To another variable. In my case it's an order model:

```
{{var order.pimpMyValue(order.getMyCustomItem().getSomething('key'))}}
```

So my **order model** contains **pimpMyValue** public method and **getMyCustomItem** method which returns **order item model**. And order item model has getSomething method which accepts one string parameter. It returns string.

So when I use first code:

```
{{var order.getMyCustomItem().getSomething('key')}}
```

It works. When I use second code (withot combaining it with another variable) it also works:

```
{{var order.pimpMyValue('my_value')}}
```

But I can't make it to work with nested variables. Is it even possible?